# Javascript WYSIWYG textarea plugins produce inconsistant results across browsers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, google-chrome, wysiwyg

I'm in need of a lightweight, Javascript-based, WYSIWYG editor that transforms `<textarea>`s into Rich Text Editors. There are thousands of these plugins out there (and I feel like I've demoed them all). For reasons outside of my control, I need the editor to produce legacy HTML... so it needs to write `<b>` instead of `<strong>` or `<span style=...>`.

Fine. No problem. There are plenty of these that purport to do just that. Here's the weirdness though: I'm finding that in a ton of these editors that I've played with, they output different things in different browsers! Chrome will output `<b>` but Firefox will output `<span style="font-weight:bold">`?!

For example, try applying **bold** in these editors in both Chrome and Firefox:

http://nicedit.com/

http://freshcode.co/plugins/jquery.contentEditable/demo.html

http://www.gosu.pl/steditor/

http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html

See? `<b>` in Chrome, but `<span style="font-weight:bold">` in Firefox. Weird!

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to browser hell.  Every browser interprets the DOM differently, I have done the unpleasant duty of making one of these editors cross compatible with just IE and Firefox and that was a pain.  I'm not aware of any really good solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I've been acquainted with browser hell many times before. This just seems above and beyond browser inconsistency though. Where is the span coming from??? Is Firefox writing it in?

Comment: Yes Firefox is writing it because the javascript is submitting it as DOM objects and Firefox then interperets it and spits out it's own variation.  Ideally there should be WYSWIG solutions out that handle this without the browsers help hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching for the less known editor, you should have started with the most commonly used ones like CKEditor and TinyMCE.

Check this sample in CKEditor:
http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/output_html.html

Comment: Okay... that's valid (although CKEditor and TinyMCE are both overkill for this project). But it still doesn't explain why browser's output is so radically different. Any thoughts?

Comment: Currently there's some effort to create a spec for the contentEditable behavior, but so far nothing existed. IE was the one that created it, then Firefox also implemented it by reverse engineering some behaviors and extending and implementing their own custom parts, finally Webkit came and did whatever they pleased without caring too much about the users (how else can you explain that they still don't allow resizing images?). You can opt to use a very simple editor and face lots of differences between browsers, or use one more developed and customize it to your needs.